# loop over rows and print data to new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My Data frame is like this:

```
     Rid          emonth             source                 Budget
      1           Jan18,Mar18        Video,webpage,email    5000
      2           Aug18              Editor,content         1200
      3           May18,Jul18        Webpage,video          300
      4           18-Dec             Designer               100
```

I tried the following to Iterate over rows in Pandas dataframe

```
 for index, row in df.iterrows():
 print(row["Rid"],df['emonth'],row['source'],row['Budget'])
```

The desired & Required output is :

```
Rid             emonth              source              Budget
1               Jan-18              Video               500
1               Mar-18              webpage             NAN
1               NAN                 email               NAN
2               Aug-18              editor              1200
2               NAN                 Content             NAN
3               May-18              webpage             300
3               Jul-18             Video                NAN
4               Dec-18              designer            100
```

Can someone help me iterate row by row and print the output into a new dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string split and expand the columns

```
# Converting all columns to string
df = df.astype(str)
# Line by line looping through each row, splitting each row series with delimiter of ',' and expanding as dataframe. 
# Transpose will return the expanded columns as rows 
df = pd.concat([df.loc[x].str.split(',',expand=True).T for x in range(len(df))],0).reset_index(drop=True)
# filling none value 'Response id' with forward fill
df['Response_id'] = df['Response_id'].ffill()
```

Out:

```
    Rid           emonth               source      Budget
0   1             Jan18               Video             5000
1   1             Mar18              webpage            None
2   1             None                email             None
3   2             Aug18               Editor            1200
4   2             None               content            None
5   3             May18              Webpage            300
6   3             Jul18                video            None
7   4             18-Dec             Designer           100
```

Comment: This doesn't return the 'Response_id' the OP specified.

Comment: @Naga Kiran This Awsome and what I exactly I'm looking for  . .Can you please explain me the logic?

Comment: yes @Mahesh i just added comments to each line of execution, with row by row splitted the each string and expanded as seperate dataframes and concated to have all dataframes as one :-)

Comment: @Naga Kiran I just run the code on my data and it's working,  Is there a way limit the number of columns to split?  I have data with 22 columns and I need only 3 colums to be split

Comment: there is no limit for columns size @Mahesh, it should work , can you ping me the error

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear, Code is running without any error, I have few columns with CSV values it should not get delimit . . .  Out of 22 columns, i want only 3 columns with CSV  to be delimited. .  So is there any way to restrict delimitation to only 3 columns?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180614/discussion-between-naga-kiran-and-mahesh).